# sql type mismatch error in multiple table query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6, multiple-tables

AM querying an access database, selecting records from two tables, in vb6 using the following query

```
SELECT stock.*,suppliers.id, suppliers.s_name as supplier FROM stock,suppliers 
WHERE stock.supplier_id=suppliers.id
```

but i get the following error when i run the query

```
-2147467259   Type mismatch in expression.   Microsoft JET Database Engine
```

can anyone tell me what is wrong

thanks

EDIT

Both stock.supplier_id, suppliers.id are long integer data type

Comment: Edit your post to include the data type of columns `stock.supplier_id` and `suppliers.id`.

Comment: Can you post the whole of the VB6 code that runs this query? Since the data types of the two fields are identical, it has to be something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stock.supplier_id` and `suppliers.id` must have compatible types for this equality to work.

There a a few converting functions available, since you have not provided the types, `CStr` should do it.

Additionally, I would advise you to avoid implicit joins:

```
SELECT stock.*,suppliers.id, suppliers.s_name as supplier 
FROM stock 
inner join suppliers 
on CStr(stock.supplier_id) = CStr(suppliers.id)
```